# TYPO3 pagepath doesn't work while page_id works fine

Tags: php, .htaccess, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I copied a TYPO3 system from live to localhost, everything is fine except I can't open any link, I can viey the page with `?id` but not with the realpath:

`www.myweb_site.com/index.php?id=17` => works

`www.myweb_site.com/travelling` => doesn't works

Things work online. Am I missing something ???

**EDIT::** 
I ativated the rewrite in my apache2 (`sudo a2enmod rewrite`)

My realurl extension is installed.

And Here is my .htaccess

```
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
  <IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 7 days"
  </IfModule>
  FileETag MTime Size
</FilesMatch>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(php|js|css|png|jpg|gif|gzip)$ $1.$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^fileadmin/(.*/)?_recycler_/ - [F]
RewriteRule ^fileadmin/templates/.*(\.txt|\.ts)$ - [F]
RewriteRule ^typo3conf/ext/[^/]+/Resources/Private/ - [F]
^/TYPO3root/(typo3/|fileadmin/|typo3conf/|typo3temp/|uploads/|favicon\.ico) - [L]
RewriteRule ^(typo3/|fileadmin/|typo3conf/|typo3temp/|uploads/|favicon\.ico) - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

With "Doesn't work" I guess you mean you get an 404 error, right?
In this case there are three possibilities.

a) Your webserver does not have the module "mod_rewrite" (in case it's an apace webserver) or the equivalent on NGINX or IIS.

b) Your webserver is not configured to use mod_rewrite. TYPO3 ships with a file called .htaccess that configures mod_rewrite. Some download tool do not download files starting with a . which could be the reason this file is missing.

c) Your TYPO3 installation does not use the extension realurl which translates the speaking url to index.php?id=...